# Two nodejs server connect to one MongoDB server at the same time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-connection, server

Is there any problem if I use two nodejs server connect to one MongoDB server at the same time?. Can this way create any read/write issue on mongo instance?.

The same question for another case: One nodejs server connect to two MongoDB server at the same time?

Comment: There is no problem with either cases. What do you mean by 'read/write issues'? If you mean transactions be aware that mongo doesn't support it yet.

Comment: @joao, I think he/she asking might be will there be any issue if one mongoDB access by tow nodejs servers, and what will happen if the both servers try to preform one of CRUD operation on mongoDB records / documents... ?